# A value is undefined in parent-child components connected together with React & Redux. App crashes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it a bug or i dont understand the React & Redux concept? My app is made of parent and child components. They are tied together by redux `connect`. Parent knows there are 12 child elements and maps them but **React do map the children starting from the ***second*** element, not first. At the end it tries to map the elements 12+2 and thereof my app is crashes with "the value of element is undefined".

I tried to pass index instead of id in the parent

```
map(el, i => <Fragment key={i}><Comp/></F...>
```

. But the app do crashes yet. Here is [parent and child with redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvjq1ml49z)

I solved my problem just removing the redux from child component and passing from parent directly to child with props.

```
map(el => (
    Fragment key={el.id}>
    <Child data={el} />...
```

Here is [parent with redux](https://codesandbox.io/s/8l3kkm1x40)

What i pursue is to pass from parent to child its id and make the child in render to find content inside the store and show it as below

```
#parent.js
...
list.map((el, i) => (
    Fragment key={i}>
    <Child id={el.id} />
...
//const mapStateToProps = state => ({list: state.list})

#child.js
render() {
    const { list, id } = this.props;
    console.log(list[id]);
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>{list[id].title}</h6>
...}

//const mapStateToProps = state => ({list: state.list})
#reducer.js
const initState = {
   list: [
       {id:1, title: 'aTitle}
       ...
       {id:12, title: 'aTitle}
    ]}
```

react 16.7.0, react-redux 6.0.0, redux 4.0.1

How to do it right and why react with redux count from 2?

Comment: list: {
       {id:1, title: 'aTitle}
       ...
       {id:12, title: 'aTitle}
    }} this object is strange, you need to provide the id as a Key around the objects like this [id] : {id:1, title: 'aTitle} if you're trying to do a hash map

Comment: @Chase that's my bad, there is the array, in the codesandboxes it's written correctly, thanks, i fixed that here

Comment: dont you have typo here `Fragment key={el.id}>`?

Comment: @TheReason you're right, i made a typo with id and searched it so long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass down an id to Child component.
And in Child component, you get list from redux and call this

```
<h6>{list[id].title}</h6>
```

but your list is an array not an object.
So you pass down id from 1 ...10

the list will return list[1], ... list[10]

1...10 here is the position of element in array, not the id that you want.

You can do it like this in the parent :

```
#parent.js
...
list.map((el, i) => (
    Fragment key={i}>
    <Child id={i} />
...
```

so i here is the position of element in array, and it will start from 0

And ofcourse id here lost the sense of id, better rename it like iterate or something

Comment: Jesus christ, that's simple! shame on me, not for the first day i code with react but did so dumb typo